# Difference between drowsiness/sedation and sleepiness

Tags: sleep

I have been trying to understand the difference between drowsiness/sedation and sleepiness. The only article I was able to find that partly answers my question is ["The difference between sedation and sleep" on ipnos.com](https://www.ipnos.com/blog/difference-sedation-sleep/).

I have experienced both, and they feel distinctly different. Sleepiness feels like a drive, but drowsiness/sedation feels like a state. My personal experience has been that sleeping when drowsy/sedated does not relieve the drowsiness/sedation, but sleeping when sleepy resolves the sleepiness.

Back to the question: **what is the neurological/neurobiological/psychopharmacological difference between sleepiness and drowsiness/sedation, and why does sleep resolve the one but not the other?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Sedation

This is a forced state of drowsiness or sleep and as indicated in your Ipnos link, it will not necessarily help with drowsiness or sleepiness brought about due to problems with your [circadian rhythm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circadian_rhythm)

[Sedation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sedation) is

> the reduction of irritability or agitation by administration of sedative drugs, generally to facilitate a medical procedure or diagnostic procedure.

### Drowsiness and Sleepiness

The terms drowsiness, sleepiness and [hypnagogic period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypnagogia) are often used to describe the same thing in the general domain, but but in the scientific domain there are important neurophysiological and psychophysiological differences.

### Hypnagogic period

This is the neurophysiological and psychophysiological transition period from the wake to sleep state.

### Drowsiness

This is the state of the transition period from the wake to sleep state **that can be objectively measured**, for example, by EEG (please see [Hori et al., 1994](https://doi.org/10.1037/10166-014))

Typical tests that describe the quality and quantity of the drowsyness are [Multiple Sleep Latency Test (MSLT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_Sleep_Latency_Test) and Maintenance of Wakefulness Test (MWT) ([Doghramji et al., 1997](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2424234)).

### Sleepiness

This is the **subjective state of the subject/patient**. It can also be qualified and quantified, but only by rating scales such as the [Stanford Sleepiness Scale (SSS)](https://web.stanford.edu/~dement/sss.html), the [Epworth Sleepiness Scale (ESS)](http://www.britishsnoring.co.uk/sleep_apnoea/epworth_sleepiness_scale.php) (See also [Johns, (1991)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/1798888)), the Karolinska Sleepiness Scale ([Åkerstedt & Gillberg, 1990](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/2265922/)), etc.

### References

Åkerstedt, T., & Gillberg, M. (1990).  Subjective and objective sleepiness in the active individual, *The International Journal of Neuroscience*, 52(1-2): pp. 29–37)
DOI: [10.3109/0020745900899424](https://doi.org/10.3109/0020745900899424) PMID: [2265922](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/2265922/)

Doghramji, K., Mitler, M. M., Sangal, R. B., Shapiro, C., Taylor, S., Walsleben, J., Belisle, C. Erman, M. K., Hayduk, R., Hosn, R., O’Malley, E. B., Sangal, J. M., Schutte, S. L., & Youakima, J. M. (1997). A normative study of the maintenance of wakefulness test (MWT), *Electroencephalography and clinical neurophysiology* 103(5): pp. 554–562.
DOI: [10.1016/S0013-4694(97)00010-2](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0013-4694(97)00010-2) PMCID: [PMC2424234](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2424234)

Hori, T., Hayashi, M., & Morikawa, T. (1994). Topographical EEG changes and the hypnagogic experience. In R. D. Ogilvie & J. R. Harsh (Eds.), *Sleep onset: Normal and abnormal processes* (pp. 237-253).
DOI: [10.1037/10166-014](https://doi.org/10.1037/10166-014)

Johns, M. W. (1991). A new method for measuring daytime sleepiness: the Epworth sleepiness scale, *Sleep* 14(6): pp. 540-545
DOI: [10.1093/sleep/14.6.540](https://doi.org/10.1093/sleep/14.6.540) PMID: [1798888](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/1798888)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It definitely helps explain the difference.